# How do I launch CKeditor plugin on event or manually?

Tags: javascript, plugins, event-handling, callback, ckeditor

So I'm using setData to prepopulate CKeditor content area with some info that is to be send together with what user inputs:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev ) {

           CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor99.setData( messageTemplate1, function() {

           this.checkDirty();  // true

           });
});
```

Before the content in "mesageTemplate1" is set to CKeditor content area I apply some JavaScript to clean it. After this I use JS again to remove the div that contained the information that i've just inserted into CKeditor content area. After the removal I want to laucn a custom CKeditor plugin to work on that content in CKeditor. It is important for this plugin to be launched after the used div removal because plugin targets ID's and if both divs are present (somewhere on the page and in ckeditor) plugin targets the one that is not in the CKeditor content area first therefor leaving the one in the ck area untouched.

This is the plugin (it blocks editing to certain content areas) I've got from a member of stack in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328681/how-to-block-editing-on-certain-part-of-content-in-ckeditor-textarea):

```
/*
  Plugin that prevents editing of elements with the "non-editable" class as well as elements outside of blocks with "editable" class.
*/

//* **************************  NOTES  ***************************  NOTES  ****************************
/*
  The "lastSelectedElement" variable is used to store the last element selected.

  This plugin uses the "elementspath" plugin which shows all elements in the DOM
  parent tree relative to the current selection in the editing area.

  When the selection changes, "elementsPathUpdate" is fired,
  we key on this and loop through the elements in the tree checking the classes assigned to each element.

  Three outcomes are possible.

  1) The non-editable class is found:
  Looping stops, the current action is cancelled and the cursor is moved to the previous selection.
  The "selectionChange" hook is fired to set the reverted selection throughout the instance.

  2) The editable class is found during looping, the "in_editable_area" flag is set to true.

  3) Neither the editable or the non-editable classes are found (user clicked outside your main container).
  The "in_editable_area" flag remains set to false.

  If the "in_editable_area" flag is false, the current action is cancelled and the cursor is moved to the previous location.
  The "selectionChange" hook is fired to set the reverted selection throughout the instance.

  If the "in_editable_area" flag is true,
  the "lastSelectedElement" is updated to the currently selected element and the plugin returns true.

---------------
  If you don't want the elements path to be displayed at the bottom of the editor window,
  you can hide it with CSS rather than disabling the "elementspath" plugin.

  The elementspath plugin creates and is left active because we are keying on changes to the path in our plugin.
  #cke_path_content
  {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }

---------------
  CSS Classes and ID that the plugin keys on. Use defaults or update variables to use your preferred classes and ID:

  var starting_element_id = ID of known editable element that always occurs in the instance.
  Don't use elements like <table>, <tr>, <br /> that don't contain HTML text.
  Default value = cwjdsjcs_editable_id

  var editable_class = class of editable containers.
  Should be applied to all top level elements that contain editable elements.
  Default = cwjdsjcs_editable

  var non_editable_class = class of non-editable elements within editable containers
  Apply to elements where all child elements are non-editable.
  Default = cwjdsjcs_not_editable

*/

//* **************************  END NOTES  ***************************  END NOTES  ****************************


// Register the plugin with the editor.
// http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.plugins.html




CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'cwjdsjcsconfineselection',
{

  requires : [ 'elementspath' ],

  // The plugin initialization logic goes inside this method.
  // http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.pluginDefinition.html#init
  init: function( editor )
  {
    editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( instance_ready_data )
    {

      // Create variable that will hold the last allowed selection (for use when a non-editable selection is made)
      var lastSelectedElement;
      editor.cwjdsjcs_just_updated = false;

      // This section starts things off right by selecting a known editable element.
      // *** Enter the ID of the element that should have initial focus *** IMPORTANT *** IMPORTANT ***
      var starting_element_id = "cwjdsjcs_editable_id";

      var resInitialRange = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );

      resInitialRange.selectNodeContents( editor.document.getById( starting_element_id ) );
      resInitialRange.collapse();

      var selectionObject = new CKEDITOR.dom.selection( editor.document );

      editor.document.focus();
      selectionObject.selectRanges( [ resInitialRange ] );

      var sel = editor.getSelection();
      var firstElement = sel.getStartElement();
      var currentPath = new CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath( firstElement );

      // Set path for known editable element, fire "selectionChange" hook to update selection throughout instance.
      editor._.selectionPreviousPath = currentPath;
      editor.fire( 'selectionChange', { selection : sel, path : currentPath, element : firstElement } );
    }); // *** END - editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( e )


    // When a new element is selected by the user, check if it's ok for them to edit it,
    // if not move cursor back to last know editable selection
    editor.on( 'elementsPathUpdate', function( resPath )
    {
      // When we fire the "selectionChange" hook at the end of this code block, the "elementsPathUpdate" hook fires.
      // No need to check because we just updated the selection, so bypass processing.
      if( editor.cwjdsjcs_just_updated == true )
      {
        editor.cwjdsjcs_just_updated = false;
        return true;
      }

      var elementsList = editor._.elementsPath.list;
      var in_editable_area = false;
      var non_editable_class = "cwjdsjcs_not_editable";
      var editable_class = "cwjdsjcs_editable";

      for(var w=0;w<elementsList.length;w++){
        var currentElement = elementsList[w];

        // Sometimes a non content element is selected, catch them and return selection to editable area.
        if(w == 0)
        {
          // Could change to switch.
          if( currentElement.getName() == "tbody" )
          {
            in_editable_area = false;
            break;
          }

          if( currentElement.getName() == "tr" )
          {
            in_editable_area = false;
            break;
          }
        }

        // If selection is inside a non-editable element, break from loop and reset selection.
        if( currentElement.hasClass(non_editable_class) )
        {
          in_editable_area = false;
          break;
        }

        if( currentElement.hasClass(editable_class) ) {
          in_editable_area = true;
        }
        console.log(currentElement);
        console.log(currentElement.getName());
      }

      // if selection is within an editable element, exit the plugin, otherwise reset selection.
      if( in_editable_area ) {
        lastSelectedElement = elementsList[0];
        return true;
      }

      var resRange = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );

      resRange.selectNodeContents( lastSelectedElement );
      resRange.collapse();
      editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ resRange ] );
      //resRange.endContainer.$.scrollIntoView();

      // Open dialog window:
      // It tells user they selected a non-editable area and cursor has been returned to previous selection
     currentEditorName = editor.name;
      openResDefaultDialog(currentEditorName);

      try
      {
        var sel = editor.getSelection();
        var firstElement = sel.getStartElement();
        var currentPath = new CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath( firstElement );
        editor.cwjdsjcs_just_updated = true;

        editor._.selectionPreviousPath = currentPath;
        editor.fire( 'selectionChange', { selection : sel, path : currentPath, element : firstElement } );

      }
      catch (e)
      {}
    });
  } // *** END - init: function( editor )
}); // ************************************************************************************* END - CKEDITOR.plugins.add
```

This is the div that is being set to CKeditor content area:

```
<table id="messageTemplate1" class="message cwjdsjcs_editable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cwjdsjcs_not_editable" contenteditable="false">
            </td>
            <td id="cwjdsjcs_editable_id">

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="cwjdsjcs_not_editable" contenteditable="false">
            <td colspan="2">
                &nbsp;

                <!-- Begin Original Content -->
                <table class="hide" style="font-size: 12px; display:none;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="hide">
                            <td>
                            Application sent by <strong><a href="http://www.globalcastingcenter.com/talent/jack-bolton">Matt Faro</a></strong> for Audition: <a href="http://www.globalcastingcenter.com:80/CustomContentRetrieve.aspx?ID=4185493">Actors Needed</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="hide">
                            <td>
                            Reply to applicant directly: mantas@mantas.co or visit full profile: http://www.globalcastingcenter.com/talent/jack-bolton
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="hide" style="font-size: 12px; display:none;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="hide">
                            <td><strong>Short Profile Summary:</strong></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table class="hide" style="font-size: 12px; display:none;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="hide">
                            <td>
                            <a href="http://www.globalcastingcenter.com/talent/jack-bolton"><img alt="" src="http://globalcastingcenter.com/talent_images/4164035_258551_foto.png?Action=thumbnail&amp;Width=144&amp;Height=215" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style="font-size: 12px; display:none;" class="hide">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="hide">
                            <td><strong>Areas:</strong></td>
                            <td>Actor,Extra</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="hide">
                            <td><strong>Country:</strong></td>
                            <td>WORLDWIDE,Any</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="hide">
                            <td><strong>Age:</strong></td>
                            <td>26</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>


            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've pasted a lot of stuff here but it all boils down to the question if and how I can launch ckeditor plugin manually or best after the removal event is completed. I also do ask if theres any more reasonable solution to my problem. Maybe plugin launching timing is not the case.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Plugin script to launch cwjdsjcsconfineselection after setData:

// JavaScript Document

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('cwjdsjcsconfineselection',
{

    requires : [ 'elementspath' ],

    init: function(editor)
    {

/*        editor.on( 'confineselection', function( confineselection_data )
    {

            alert ("Blocker is on!");




        }); // editor on END

*/      

        editor.on( 'confineselection', function( confineselection_data )
    {
        alert ("Plugin fired!");

      // Create variable that will hold the last allowed selection (for use when a non-editable selection is made)
      var lastSelectedElement;
      editor.cwjdsjcs_just_updated = false;

      // This section starts things off right by selecting a known editable element.
      // *** Enter the ID of the element that should have initial focus *** IMPORTANT *** IMPORTANT ***
      var starting_element_id = "cwjdsjcs_editable_id";

      var resInitialRange = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );

      resInitialRange.selectNodeContents( editor.document.getById( starting_element_id ) );
      resInitialRange.collapse();

      var selectionObject = new CKEDITOR.dom.selection( editor.document );

      editor.document.focus();
      selectionObject.selectRanges( [ resInitialRange ] );

      var sel = editor.getSelection();
      var firstElement = sel.getStartElement();
      var currentPath = new CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath( firstElement );

      // Set path for known editable element, fire "selectionChange" hook to update selection throughout instance.
      editor._.selectionPreviousPath = currentPath;
      editor.fire( 'selectionChange', { selection : sel, path : currentPath, element : firstElement } );
    }); // *** END - editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( e )


    // When a new element is selected by the user, check if it's ok for them to edit it,
    // if not move cursor back to last know editable selection
    editor.on( 'elementsPathUpdate', function( resPath )
    {
      // When we fire the "selectionChange" hook at the end of this code block, the "elementsPathUpdate" hook fires.
      // No need to check because we just updated the selection, so bypass processing.
      if( editor.cwjdsjcs_just_updated == true )
      {
        editor.cwjdsjcs_just_updated = false;
        return true;
      }

      var elementsList = editor._.elementsPath.list;
      var in_editable_area = false;
      var non_editable_class = "cwjdsjcs_not_editable";
      var editable_class = "cwjdsjcs_editable";

      for(var w=0;w<elementsList.length;w++){
        var currentElement = elementsList[w];

        // Sometimes a non content element is selected, catch them and return selection to editable area.
        if(w == 0)
        {
          // Could change to switch.
          if( currentElement.getName() == "tbody" )
          {
            in_editable_area = false;
            break;
          }

          if( currentElement.getName() == "tr" )
          {
            in_editable_area = false;
            break;
          }
        }

        // If selection is inside a non-editable element, break from loop and reset selection.
        if( currentElement.hasClass(non_editable_class) )
        {
          in_editable_area = false;
          break;
        }

        if( currentElement.hasClass(editable_class) ) {
          in_editable_area = true;
        }
        console.log(currentElement);
        console.log(currentElement.getName());
      }

      // if selection is within an editable element, exit the plugin, otherwise reset selection.
      if( in_editable_area ) {
        lastSelectedElement = elementsList[0];
        return true;
      }

      var resRange = new CKEDITOR.dom.range( editor.document );

      resRange.selectNodeContents( lastSelectedElement );
      resRange.collapse();
      editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ resRange ] );
      //resRange.endContainer.$.scrollIntoView();

      // Open dialog window:
      // It tells user they selected a non-editable area and cursor has been returned to previous selection
     currentEditorName = editor.name;
      openResDefaultDialog(currentEditorName);

      try
      {
        var sel = editor.getSelection();
        var firstElement = sel.getStartElement();
        var currentPath = new CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath( firstElement );
        editor.cwjdsjcs_just_updated = true;

        editor._.selectionPreviousPath = currentPath;
        editor.fire( 'selectionChange', { selection : sel, path : currentPath, element : firstElement } );

      }
      catch (e)
      {}
    }); // Blocker source END

        editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( ev )
                {       
                    var messageTemplate1 = $("#messageTemplate1").html();

                    CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor99.setData( messageTemplate1, function() 

                    {
                        alert ("setData done!");             
                        this.checkDirty();  // true


                    }); 

                    CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor99.fire( 'confineselection' );


                });

    } // init END

}); // Plugin add END
```

There is still problem with transform handles appearing around the table. This only happens in Firefox, this is the video: http://screencast.com/t/lxKJWb6NI Sometimes this box disapear after refresh and sometimes not. Login details are in my comments if you'd like to test it live.

This is my config:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{


    config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';

    config.toolbar_MyToolbar =
    [

        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Undo','Redo' ] },           
        { name: 'styles', items : ['FontSize' ] },
        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic'] },
        { name: 'paragraph', items : ['Outdent','Indent' ] },

    ];
    config.startupShowBorders = false;
    config.disableObjectResizing = true;


    config.removePlugins = 'contextmenu';
    config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;   
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles = true;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = true;
    config.extraPlugins = 'cwjdsjcsconfineselection';




};
```

Comment: It might be helpful to someone in the future if you link to your question that resulted in the plugin code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try firing an event after you remove the div:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.ckeditor99.fire( 'confineselection' );
```

---

Change this line of the plugin code from:

```
    editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( instance_ready_data )
    {
```

To this:

```
    editor.on( 'confineselection', function( confineselection_data )
    {
```

You might want to move the block of code that fires on elementsPathUpdate, inside the other block of code. So this:

```
    editor.on( 'confineselection', function( confineselection_data )
    {
      ......................................................
      ......................................................
      // Set path for known editable element, fire "selectionChange" hook to update selection throughout instance.
      editor._.selectionPreviousPath = currentPath;
      editor.fire( 'selectionChange', { selection : sel, path : currentPath, element : firstElement } );
    }); // *** END - editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( e )


    // When a new element is selected by the user, check if it's ok for them to edit it,
    // if not move cursor back to last know editable selection
    editor.on( 'elementsPathUpdate', function( resPath )
    {
      ......................................................
      ......................................................
      catch (e)
      {}
    });
```

Becomes this:

```
    editor.on( 'confineselection', function( confineselection_data )
    {
      ......................................................
      ......................................................
      // Set path for known editable element, fire "selectionChange" hook to update selection throughout instance.
      editor._.selectionPreviousPath = currentPath;
      editor.fire( 'selectionChange', { selection : sel, path : currentPath, element : firstElement } );


      // When a new element is selected by the user, check if it's ok for them to edit it,
      // if not move cursor back to last know editable selection
      editor.on( 'elementsPathUpdate', function( resPath )
      {
        ......................................................
        ......................................................
        catch (e)
        {}
      });      

    }); // *** END - editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( e )
```

Comment: I've finally managed to get this working after setData, but the problem with Firefox still persists. All other browsers are displaying editable area without borders but in firefox you have these some kind of transforming box handles. You can try this here: http://gcc-july.themantas.co.uk/auditions/actors-needed username: gaga pssw: test i'm inserting plugin code with eventlistener and setData in my question. Because it works fine, it seems that setData happens before plugin runs but alert messages suggest otherwise.

Comment: This is the video of the transform box that apears: http://screencast.com/t/lxKJWb6NI

Comment: I took a look. Regarding the order of the alerts, it takes time to `setData()`, so the next alert happens before `setData()` finishes. Move the `fire()` just after the `this.checkDirty();` to be safe. Try `this.fire()`.

Comment: The handles in Firefox look different (not dotted lines), it might be useful to `console.log(xxx)`, where "xxx" = the editor, then you can check the values of the config settings. What happens if you don't set those two config settings? There's a config setting that's specific to Firefox `config.disableNativeTableHandles`, the default is true. Maybe something changed in Firefox and the code for that setting no longer works. This is really a different question and you might get more help if you create a question specifically about the table re-size handles appearing in Firefox.