# ckeditor: protect a zone

Tags: ckeditor

I have a text coming from database and put in a ckeditor editor. I want to protect a zone in my text.

Example:

```
<div class="editable">aaaaa</div>
<div class="non-editable">bbbbb</div>
<div class="editable">aaaaa</div>
```

My wish is that the `div` with class `non-editable` come like a readonly text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to block editing on certain part of content in CKEDITOR textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328681/how-to-block-editing-on-certain-part-of-content-in-ckeditor-textarea) (as referenced in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I wrote a plugin for it. You can find the plugin in this answer:
[How to block editing on certain part of content in CKEDITOR textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11370552/751619)

You'll need to adjust some things, like the classes to make sure they match across your HTML and the plugin code because the plugin code checks for the protected class and blocks any changes to the elements inside the protected class.

I put a lot of documentation within the plugin code to explain how it works. It might be best to start off with the HTML included in the answer so that you can get a working version, then modify the HTML to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I test your plugin this week.