# CKEditor plugin to set classes

Tags: javascript, plugins, colors, ckeditor, wysiwyg

What I want to do is something similar to the native foreground / background colors dialog. The difference is, it will have buttons with colors directly in a toolbar. So one plugin has to have multiple buttons, with different styles (colors). The other problem is, that this native plugin sets CSS `color` and `background-color` properties. I need to use classes instead, like this:

```
text <span class="fg red">colored text</span> text
```

and

```
text <span class="bg blue">colored background</span> text
```

Clicking into colors have to change color of a span with `fg` class (and background colors - `bg` class)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to add your own buttons. Check source of any plugin that does this -  e.g. [`basicstyles/plugin.js`](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/basicstyles/plugin.js). You've got to create command for each button and then register all buttons. Simple.

Then I propose to use our styles implementation. It allows to apply/remove defined style from the given selection/range. In the style definition you can specify that it will apply `span` element with given classes. Check [this style](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/styles.js#L59) definition.

And the last step - join these things together. Command associated with button should apply/remove this style. There's ready to use one - check `CKEDITOR.styleCommand` usage [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/basicstyles/plugin.js#L22).

Everything you need is in `basicstyles` plugin, so just refer there.

Pozdrawiam :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're flexible about the interface, you could just add your styles to the ["Styles" selector](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles).

It would be less work than creating your own plugin. Especially if you're using CKEditor 3.6 or later where you could use the new [Stylesheet Parser Plugin](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles#Stylesheet_Parser_Plugin).

---

You're welcome to use the plugin from the [answer where you asked me to look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7685232/751619).

It's based on the "basicstyles" plugin. If you look at the comments I included, you'll see that you can use it to add multiple buttons and multiple styles.

```
// This "addButtonCommand" function isn't needed, but
// would be useful if you want to add multiple buttons
```

You would have multiple calls to the `addButtonCommand` method.

```
addButtonCommand( 'Fg_red'   , 'Label'   , 'fg_red'   , config.coreStyles_fg_red );
addButtonCommand( 'Bg_blue'   , 'Label'   , 'bg_blue'   , config.coreStyles_bg_blue );
```

The last line of code after the plugin code is what you add to your configuration. You can use any attributes that you like:

```
CKEDITOR.config.coreStyles_fg_red = { element : 'span', attributes : { 'class': 'fg red' } };
CKEDITOR.config.coreStyles_bg_blue = { element : 'span', attributes : { 'class': 'bg blue' } };
```

---

You could also create a plugin based on the "colorbutton" plugin. It creates the native foreground / background colors dialog.