# CkEditor - 2 styles at the same time...?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Is there a way to add more than one class with ckeditor style list ?

I have two class in my ckeditor.style.js

```
{ name: 'Important (petit)', element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'important-small' } },
{ name: 'Capitalize', element: 'p', attributes: { 'class': 'caps' } },
```

I want, if you select via the style list the two classes this result :

```
<p class="important-small caps">my test</p>
```

But if I select one class and another one just after, the first class disappear, replaced by the second

Answer (score 1):

You are [not the first to encounter this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510288/how-to-apply-multiple-styles-to-one-element-in-ckeditor)

However, CKEditor does not currently support setting two styles on the same element from their dropdown. Have a look at [this](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11120) or [this](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/5980) ticket in their tracker.

If adding the classes in the source view is not an option you may have to write your own plugin (like [this SO user is doing for colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676144/ckeditor-format-class).